# If someone calls something by a wrong name, what are they actually referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, objects

I was in an argument where an analogy was raised concerning animals often called by technically incorrect terms. Let's say the case in question was "panda bear".

It became clear we were using the analogy differently, so it actually confused the situation. We agreed on these statements:

- I know a panda is not a true bear.
- I expect that a person using the phrase "panda bear" probably doesn't know that.

So the question is, if someone says "panda bear", what are they referring to?

My interpretation: I don't care what family they think it's in. They're visualizing the same black and white bamboo-eating creature you and I am. They're referring to the giant panda.

His interpretation: They're using a phrase that means something that is both a panda and a bear. Since there is no such animal, they're referring to something that doesn't exist.

Is either of us wrong here, or is this a subjective question? (And is this actually an English question or a philosophy question?)

Comment: though apparently pandas are bears at the moment, having been reclassified in the 90s following molecular studies. :)

Comment: @Spagirl But, but... is Wellington a bear? And what about Rupert?

Comment: @Mick Who is Wellington? Do you mean Paddington?

Comment: @Spagirl You're right. It helps if you've read the books (or seen the film).

Comment: @Mick Paddington is an Andean or Spectacled Bear, *Tremarctos ornatus*. Rupert is a hairy kid.

Comment: Rupert is a hairy kid -- with hairy middle-class parents too (and a very dodgy professor friend who lives in a tower with a dwarf). Tigerlilly is OK, though.

Comment: @Mick  grew up loving the Paddington books, the strange verse-form story-telling, in what was essentially a comic strip, in the Rupert books left me cold.

Comment: I would call your friend's argument essentially a philosophical one, along the lines of "when I say the grass is green and you say the grass is green, do we *really* see that color the same way? Or if I somehow jumped into your consciousness, would I suddenly think the grass is orange or pink or some color I've never seen before?"

Comment: Would your friend also refuse the existence of tomatoes at the grocery store because they put them with the vegetables instead of with the berries? Or the existence of _The Lion Sleeps Tonight_ because lions don't live in jungles? The actual question here is, I'm afraid, more a matter of philosophy than English and cannot really be answered authoritatively; but it's very obvious that your friend's position cannot withstand even a fleeting  amount of logical scrutiny—if for no other reason then because he's trying to tell someone else what they're referring to, which he cannot.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - "Would your friend also refuse the existence of tomatoes at the grocery store because they put them with the vegetables instead of with the berries?" ... I have a friend like that.  He probably would, yes.

Comment: Pandas are bears. But Koalas ate often wrongly referred to as bears. Nevertheless, I think this question should be moved to Philosophy, as it not language depended.

Comment: And my brain seems to throw in a new curve.  Every time I read "panda bear", I visualized a koala...  {palmface}

Comment: There are all kinds of *slightly*, *technically* incorrect language uses that people perpetrate all the time, and some people like to get into fights over them – such as it appears your friend here does. He would probably also argue that anyone referring to a "[ATM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine) machine" was referring to a fictional (potentially undefined) device which is indistinguishable from a real, extant machine which dispenses cash to authenticated users. Others realize that requiring such precision in everyday speech is counterproductive and makes people mad.

Comment: I would really like to create a question for the site along the lines of "If someone refers to situation but their given example is not actually an example of that situation, what are they actually referring to?" But I don't think that's a pithy enough title so instead I'm just leaving this comment

Comment: There is (with 'koala bear') a conflict of registers.

Comment: I agree that this is a philosophy question. It's related to the "present King of France" problem in the philosophy of language.

Comment: I asked a friend of mine, and he sent me a link to https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~eg35/4617referential.pdf  It seems that I and the other person were *both* right. It's the difference between speaker's referent (what I was using) and semantic referent (what he was using).

Comment: I argue that my question *isn't* an opinion question. I asked which of three cases was true: I'm right, he's right, or it's subjective. IE, saying "It's a matter of opinion" *is a possible answer to the actual question*. (And the one I now believe is right.)

Answer (score 12):

We need to think about the speaker and listener in all communications, and bear in mind that all communication requires inference on the part of the listener, in order to correctly interpret what the speaker is trying to say.  Communication requires pragmatism from both parties.

So, when someone says "panda bear", they could be talking about **anything**.  It could be the nickname of one of their colleagues.  You might **decide** that they are referring to Ailuropoda melanoleuca, better known as the Giant Panda.  This interpretation doesn't depend on whether the species happens to be in the bear family or not.  Imagine that they'd said Beary McBambooFace instead, and you happened to have that as a private joke for referring to Pandas.  It's just your interpretation of what they mean.

If your interpretation of what they mean matches what they were actually trying to say, then that was a successful communication.  If it doesn't, it was a failed communication.  That's the important distinction.

If the communication failed, then you could go on to post-mortem it and decide who was mostly to blame for the mismatch between reference and interpretation.

If the listener **decides** that the entire communication is null and void because pandas are not bears (whether they actually are or not), then they are most likely to blame, since they did actually guess the right meaning, but refused to accept it.

In other words, one shouldn't be a robot: one should use common sense, which is essential for all communication.  Using this as a guide, I think you are right and your friend is wrong.

Comment: It's great to see a hand trumped with the *common sense* card.

Comment: @Davo The words *Trump* and *common sense* don't really fit well together.

Comment: *"bear in mind"*...

Comment: "one shouldn't be a robot" I disagree, one should be a smarter robot.

Comment: I'm would be tempted to use the term "common courtesy" to expect a person in a discussion to try to understand my main thrust rather than looking for semantic flaws in my wording. (I mean they could correct me with the use of "never" or "always" by saying, "I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you mean "usually" but not only can I think of rare exceptions x and y, I think your general thrust is also wrong because of Z" ... Not... "I know one way your statement is wrong, hence everything else you might be trying to express is meaningless".) However, courtesy is subjective.

Comment: +1 for the use of *Beary McBambooFace* in a serious answer.

Comment: *and bear in mind that all communication requires inference on the part of the listener* -- Don't you mean "*panda* in mind"?

Answer (score 7):

> So the question is, if someone says "panda bear", what are they referring to?

Well, they are referring to either a panda or a bear, unless it is something else entirely.

The technical term for the object being referred to (whether concrete or abstract) is a *referent*:

> **referent** noun [ C ] specialized
>
> the person, thing, or idea that a word, phrase, or object refers to:
>
> - The obvious textual referent in this movie is Shakespeare's "Hamlet".

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/referent)

And the technical term for this kind of mistake is a *misnomer*:

> **misnomer** noun [ C ]
>
> a name that does not suit what it refers to, or the use of such a name:
>
> - It was the scruffiest place I've ever stayed in, so "Grand Hotel" was a complete misnomer.
> - It's something of a misnomer to refer to these inexperienced boys as soldiers.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misnomer)

Comment: +1 for misnomer, which would have been my answer too.

Comment: So which part is the misnomer in "panda bear"? The "panda" or the "bear" bit? Is defining a panda a "bear" a misnomer? It's not exactly wrong or misjudged, is it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA A zoologist would probably say that it is; a layman, perhaps not. I just used the OP's example.

Comment: Just too bad the example in the question _isn’t_ an actual misnomer, since a panda _is_ a bear.

Answer (score 4):

"A rose by any other name would smell as sweet" except, perhaps, to a pedant.

The assignation of a name to anything, concrete or abstract, is a social contract. As educated elites, experts certainly have their input, but if enough people want to call a Douglas fir by that name, even though it's not really a fir tree, then so be it.

Comment: This is a much less waffly way to say what I said in my answer. :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes, but I think to get the full feel of why being pedantic is anti-social and understand the broader pejorative connotation, your answer is very important even though KarlG s might be more clear if one had a sense of the word.

Comment: Peanuts are not nuts, but that does not mean "peanut" is the wrong word to use to describe a peanut.

Answer (score 1):

To be neither pedantic or overly zoological, history has amply rewarded us with misnamed things but neither technological developments or conventions are likely to change these in the public perception. I'm thinking here about koala bears (a marsupial) and North American "Indians" (so called because when he encountered them, Columbus believe them to be inhabitants of India, considering that he had reached the eastern coast of Asia). 
However , the fact remains that unless you are a zoologist, historian or academic, a thing is often named incorrectly but English (or languages in general) is not solely the domain of academics (as we and they may use it differently and with different intentions), the act of referring to an object by a universally-accepted name, though technically incorrect) has the desired effect of aiding communications between people, while using the technically correct name, serves only to make communications more uncertain or inefficient, and to position the speaker as privileged, pedantic, superior or obtuse, EVEN if to continually use the correct name may result in a dual name being used and eventually, perhaps one becoming more dominant or publicly favoured (faucet/spigot/tap, highway/freeway, trainers/sneakers, etc., etc..).
The question was asked: "is this in the area of etymology or philosophy?" Answer: Right now this is descending into Scotland's weirdest sword dance involving linguistics, sociology, psychology and history.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv2Av.jpg)

Comment: I know the point of this answer is to not be too pedantic, but I'm going to be pedantic anyway. They are called "Indians" because Columbus believed them to be inhabitants of the East Indies, not mainland India

Comment: This answer looks interesting but I can't deal with giant blocks of unparagraphed text this early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

According to wiki the animal family pandas belong to is a type of bear.  What wiki states is a red panda is not a real bear.
Where are you getting the information that pandas are not bears?
Your question is not applicable with pandas.  They are in fact classified as bears.

Comment: Good as a comment, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have edited the answer.  However the answer implies pandas are bears as referenced.  So the op has made a mistake saying it is referring to the wrong name.

Comment: Let's pretend the *panda bear* is only an example, what would you call the act of calling something by its **non-technical** erroneous term? For instance, (one of my favorite trivia fun fact) calling the banana plant  a ["banana tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana#Description) when, technically speaking, it is a herb.

Comment: And it is only an example (it was actually a different animal, I changed it so the other person wouldn't find this thread.)

Answer (score 0):

From a philosophical point of view, you have two different languages. It is not relevant how far apart the meanings of the words are, or if it is a word in the given language at all. What person A calls a Panda, might be called an elephant or a hongxthevetn by person B. You may call B's language Near-English or L2 or anything you want.